# The Walmart Marketplace OAuth API keeps throwing SYSTEM_ERROR.GMP_GATEWAY_API error

Tags: javascript, xml, api, rest, walmart-api

I’ve been trying to authenticate with the Walmart Marketplace API for both sandbox and production but have so far been unsuccessful. In all cases when I ping a request to the “Token API” (https://sandbox.walmartapis.com/v3/token) I get back the the following error code: “SYSTEM_ERROR.GMP_GATEWAY_API”. I’ve tried to authenticate with both JSON and XML but no luck.

Here is my request with JSON:

```
{
  url: 'https://sandbox.walmartapis.com/v3/token',
  data: { grant_type: 'client_credentials' },
  options: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic <base64String>=',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'WM_SVC.NAME': 'Walmart Marketplace',
      'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID': '1bca34cd-478f-4022-8c13-9b88293f56b2',
      'WM_SVC.VERSION': '1.0.0'
    }
  },
  method: 'post'
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting with JSON:

```
error: [
    {
      code: 'SYSTEM_ERROR.GMP_GATEWAY_API',
      description: 'Illegal character in query at index 172: http://partner-read-srvc-app.prod2.partnerreadservice1.catdev.prod.walmart.com/partner-read-srvc-app/services/org/client/search?_s=cross_ref_key==ClientId;cross_ref_value=="8cdc9a4f-3518-4941-9b62-5bc88bac5f3c;buId==0;martId==0',
      info: 'System encountered some internal error.',
      severity: 'ERROR',
      category: 'DATA',
      causes: [],
      errorIdentifiers: {}
    }
```

The error mentions index 172 but I'm not exactly sure what it's referring to. Having looked at their docs [here](https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace/latest#apiAuthentication) I'm following the implementation to the letter.

Here is my request for XML:

```
{
  url: 'https://sandbox.walmartapis.com/v3/token',
  data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\n' +
    '<grant_type>client_credentials</grant_type>',
  options: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic <base64String>=',
      Accept: 'application/xml',
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml',   
      'WM_SVC.NAME': 'Walmart Marketplace',
      'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID': 'be1ff777-9c7b-4ca2-8b9c-ac31696dbf79',
    }
  },
  method: 'post'
}
```

But this is also fails.

Does anyone know why these requests may be failing and perhaps provide a working example in JS of a request to authenticate with the API?

Comment: Is the '=' after the <base64String> part of your JSON template, or an editing error?  Use " for quotes, and maybe check a sample with a JSON validator.  Other than that it looks ok at first glance.  I've got code for getting a token, but not in JS.  If that doesn't work, can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'https://sandbox.walmartapis.com/v3/token',
  'headers': {
    'WM_SVC.NAME': 'Walmart Marketplace',
    'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID': 'test',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic afafaf...',
    'WM_SVC.VERSION': ' 1.0.0',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  form: {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

This works for me. Make sure you have the Authorization build correctly. it is in the format "Basic Base64encode(cliendId:clientSecret)"

I think the they way you are sending the grant_type attribute is incorrect.

Comment: thanks for response @kushan85. So in the end, since this is a 3rd party development, the issue was with the API credentials not being correctly activated by client!